# Starting an AppCompatActivity Activity from a class that extends Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have been through a lot of posts here about starting an activity from a fragment, although none of them seem to be solving my problem. As i say, i am trying to start an activity from a class that extends a fragment. At the minute, when i remove the "android:onClick" from the xml, the button simply becomes dead and it does not let me click it. However when i put in the OnClick method to the xml i receive the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'buttonViewDetails'
>                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
>                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
>                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5653)
>                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22509)
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6144)
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

I am not quite sure what this means. Here is the code that i have tried:

Button XML inside the class extending fragment:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonViewDetails"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@mipmap/info"
    android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp" />
```

Java Code for the class that extends fragment:

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View myInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.line_details, container, false);

    Bundle extras = getArguments();
    if (extras != null) {
        String linetype = extras.getString("LineType");
        TextView LT = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textViewLineType);
        LT.setText(linetype);

        Button InfoButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.buttonViewDetails);
        InfoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), VerifyLine.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    return myInflatedView;
}
```

Would anyone be able to help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: remove  `android:onClick="onClick"` expecting your activity to have onClick method with view as param

Comment: doesn't required to set InfoButton.setOnClickListener( . Just define your onClick () method in your fragment

Comment: when i remove the android:onClick="onClick" the button just becomes stale and doesnt click or do anything?

Comment: by define it in the fragment do you mean the java class that is extending the fragment? also how do i define it? im a beginner!

Comment: @AaronRogers3 you should read the android docs. button should be clickable.

Comment: @AaronRogers3 also your finding views in activity layout  or fragment layout. if in fragment you need to use myInflatedView. findViewById instead of getActivity().findViewById and this is covered in the fragment docs if you read

Comment: Yeah i changed that now.. only problem is button is still doing nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inflating a view myInflatedView and doing findViewById of that view using activity reference.So ust change that getActivity and use myInflatedView to find the Views.Also remove onClick for the button from xml.

```
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View myInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.line_details, container, false);

        TextView LT = (TextView) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.textViewLineType);
        Button InfoButton = (Button) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.buttonViewDetails);
        InfoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), VerifyLine.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        Bundle extras = getArguments();
        if (extras != null) {
            String linetype = extras.getString("LineType");
            LT.setText(linetype);
        }

        return myInflatedView;
    }
```

Comment: when you are inflating a view for the fragment the ids are present in the particular fragment..getActivity() will give you the activity reference.

Comment: I tried this too and the button is still not clickable??

Comment: remove this line android:onClick="onClick"

Comment: Yeah i have done that: i will update my xml for the button above